# Vuex Mutation is already set with the new payload before the function is run

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

```
setScorecardActiveVerificationsList(state, payload) {
    console.log(
      'beginState :>> ',
      state.activeScorecardVerificationsList
    )
    const findIndex = state.activeScorecardVerificationsList.findIndex(
      (el) => el.part_id === payload.part_id
    )
    console.log('findIndex', findIndex)
    if (findIndex !== -1) {
      const newArray = state.activeScorecardVerificationsList.filter(
        (el) => el.part_id !== payload.part_id
      )
      newArray.push(payload)
      state.activeScorecardVerificationsList = newArray
      console.log(
        'FoundstateactiveScorecardVerificationsList',
        state.activeScorecardVerificationsList
      )
    } else {
      state.activeScorecardVerificationsList = [
        ...state.activeScorecardVerificationsList,
        payload,
      ]
      console.log(
        'NotFoundactiveScorecardVerificationsList',
        state.activeScorecardVerificationsList
      )
    }
  },
```

I'm still a bit new to Vuex but I'm having trouble with this mutation. This mutation format I've used on two other parts of the code that are working fine so this one is stumping me.

Btw, state.activeScorecardVerificationsList is an array of Objects.

I'm checking to see if the payload with part_id is already existing in the state.
IF it exists, I want to overwrite it and return the state with the newly updated object in the array.
IF this payload with the part_id does not exist, I just want to add it to the array.

Currently I'm having trouble with this part of the code:

```
console.log(
      'beginState :>> ',
      state.activeScorecardVerificationsList
    )
    const findIndex = state.activeScorecardVerificationsList.findIndex(
      (el) => el.part_id === payload.part_id
    )
```

For some reason, the beginState console log is showing the state with the payload.part_id (new one) almost immediately before any of the other lines of function is run. therefore, findIndex is returning 0 and it is always overwriting the state, not adding to it.

I'm not entirely sure how the state is already being sent with the new payload. I have a feeling my syntax or understanding of setting a vuex mutation might be off

Any ideas?

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem line but cannot figure it out. In the component that is using this state, if I comment out the vuex state and/or the html using the state, the problem will go away. What is it about the template or vuex usage that would cause this issue?

Comment: The code doesn't seems to be wrong. Where are you committing the mutations?? Check if they are accidentally triggered twice?? Also you said its always returning 0 in findIndex, so is the console.log in the else clause the same as the beginState one?? 
One solution would be to create an action for this logic and then committing the mutation with the new payload.

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq Yea it’s weird I’m tearing my hair out lol. I’ve checked everywhere to see if this mutation is being triggered i even started again from scratch using different names. If I comment out the html code using the vuex store it seems to track fine. I can probably write another action for this logic I’ll probably try that but it’s weird I’ll have to dispatch one action to get the data and another to clean it